# error while compiling Objective c in GNUStep in ubuntu

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors, gnustep

showing this error while trying to compile my program.

```
error: #error The current setting for native-objc-exceptions does not match that of gnustep-base ... please correct this.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good idea to install GNUstep from trunk rather using distributor's packages and also ditch gcc for clang.

Some useful build script. It even fetch things from svn for you.
http://svn.gna.org/svn/etoile/trunk/Etoile/BuildScripts/